# Image as an Icon for NavigationView Item

Tags: java, android, image, material-design, navigationview

I'm looking to use a full color image as the icon for a menu item in a NavigationView. The image would need to be larger than the standard icons, and not have a color tint. (Like a profile image) I've found ways to both change the icon size but not on specific items. It looks like you have to change a global, private attribute for that to work. Is using a app:actionLayout that defines the entire item my only option?

[image: Here is a screenshot]

from Google's Calendar app which shows exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Without creating a custom drawer, the only way is adding a header layout (app:headerLayout):

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

If you want a more customizable nav drawer, I recommend this one:
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer